# Battery level for playing video in android

Tags: android

At which battery level video cannot played by videoview in android?

The level which is received by broadcast from

```
Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
```

This intent will return battery level like 1,2....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> At which battery level video cannot played by videoview in android?

0, presumably.